# Drawing graph with a function with respect to f(y)=x with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i draw piecewise function(which is below)  with tikzpicture? I can draw any function with respect to x but i have no idea about the variable y ? thanks  in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\begin{document}   

\begin{cases}
      1 & \mbox{,if } y<\frac{1}{4} \\
      $[0,1]$ & \mbox{,if }  y=\frac{1}{4} \\
      0 & \mbox{,if}\, \, y>\frac{1}{4}.
\end{cases} %it is the function that i want to draw.
\\ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis} [xtick={0,0.1,...,1.1},ytick={0,0.1,...,1.1},xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,ymin=-0.1,ymax=1.1,xmax=1.1,xmin=-0.001,axis on top=true,axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle, width=10cm, grid=major,legend pos=outer north east
]

\addplot [yellow, line width=3,variable=\y,smooth,domain=1/2:1] {1};
\addplot [yellow, line width=3,variable=\x,smooth,domain=0:1] {1};
\addplot [yellow, line width=3,variable=\y,smooth,domain=0:1/2] {1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this is what i do so far

Comment: What do you mean with "below with tikzpicture"? Please post a MWE to help us help you.

Comment: Please see the link about the minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). And add the compilable code(MWE), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i added some codes that what i do so far, thanks in advance for you help @TeXnician

Comment: i added some codes that what i do so far, thanks in advance for you help @Bobyandbob

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Tick/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}
                    ]
% axes
\draw[draw=gray,thin,-Straight Barb] (-4,0) -- (4,0)    node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[draw=gray,thin,-Straight Barb] (0,-1) -- (0,2)    node[below left] {$y$};
% function
\draw[draw=red,thick]   (  -3,1) -- (0.5,1)
                        (0.5,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[red,densely dashed,thin]  (0.5,1) -- + (0,-1);
% ticks
\foreach \i in {-1,-0.5,0, 0.25, 1}
    \draw[thin] (2*\i,0) -- + (0,-0.1) node[Tick, below] {$\i$};
\node[Tick, left] at (-1mm,1) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
It seems that function is x = f(y) ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Tick/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}
                    ]
% axes
\draw[draw=gray,thin,-Straight Barb] (-1,0) -- (3,0)    node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[draw=gray,thin,-Straight Barb] (0,-1) -- (0,2)    node[below left] {$y$};
% function
\draw[draw=red,thick]   (0,1.5) -- + (0,-1)
                        (2,0.5) -- + (0,-1);
\draw[red,densely dashed,thin]  (0,0.5) -- + (2,0);
% ticks
\node[Tick,left]  at (-0.1, 0.5) {$\frac{1}{4}$};
\foreach \i in {0,1}
    \node[Tick,below] at (2*\i,-0.1) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: He wants to draw a function of y, not a function of x, so perhaps he wants the plot to be two vertical lines, and the dashed one horizontal. (It's not entirely clear to me though.)

Comment: \draw[draw=red,thick]  (0,0.25) -- (0,1)
                                        (0,0.25) -- (1,0.25)
                                        (1,0.25) -- (1,0);
it needs to be like that but , when i coded nothing will appear, so i think have a missing package or something ?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., probably you have right. I will wait what will OP say :)

Comment: @AlperErdem, code is complete and nothing is missing, but the point 0.25 is on wrong place. It is corrected now.

Comment: @AlperErdem, sorry but link doesn't work there is no image

Comment: @Zarko i added the new link :) ---> https://ibb.co/meyZvk

Comment: @AlperErdem, you are welcome! If the answer is solve your problem, you can accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). This is usual way to say "thank you" here  :)